# JavaScript Heap Size and Chrome Increasing

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, google-chrome, heap-memory

I have a single web page application that is all JavaScript.  I noticed the JavaScript heap size goes up on each AJAX call that returns a new view.  Is there something I should be doing to clean up the older views?

Comment: Are you ensuring that you are not (mis)using global variables?

Comment: Obvious but have you compared heap snapshots in Chrome? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling

Comment: Yes I have closures for all my pages that create objects so no global variables.  I have a single namespace.

Comment: Are you using a framework ie Backbone, YUI, etc? Is this an EDA app? If so, you need to make sure event subscriptions are cleaned up from the DOM properly.

Comment: if u are not using cache memory , then set cache : false in your ajax calls

Comment: Can you post a simple code example?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to take a look at the following resources. You can see how to inspect the browser timeline in order to detect leaking references and performance problems.

The first one is from a Chrome developer talking this year at the Google IO:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pxf3Ju2row

The second one is from Paul Irish talking at the breaking point episode 2:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPXeWjWp-8Y

I'm sure you will find a lot of clues!!
Anyway ... if you share a test case of your code at jsfiddle.net, we can take a look :)